# Lucene: sort by numeric field

Tags: content-search

I am trying to sort results by a decimal field, but it doesn't work. I need to use the property name indexer on the standard `SearchResultItem` so that it can be dynamic.

```csharp
return queryable.OrderBy(i => i["price"]);
```

I have a string & DateTime fields that work fine using:

```csharp
return queryable.OrderBy(i => i["date"]);
return queryable.OrderBy(i => i["title"]);
```

Config:

```xml
<field fieldName="price" 
   storageType="YES" 
   indexType="UNTOKENIZED" 
   vectorType="NO" 
   boost="1f" 
   type="System.Single" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />`
```

I have also tried `System.Double` , `System.Decimal` for the type but still no luck.

Update: field in Luke:

[image: Luke]

Comment: If you use luke, Can you check what format your field is being stored in? https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/downloads

Comment: I've updated the question to show the field in Luke.

Comment: Could you try "System.Double" again, rebuild the index and use the code example i provided below? i changed the conversion from float to double

Comment: Still no joy :(

Comment: I Updated my answer to include a patch file to force sitecore to use IndexFieldFloatingPointNumberValueConverter for double values

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go. Meanwhile I tried using the standard approach (like Andrei suggested) `return queryable.Cast<TestClass>().OrderBy(i => i.Price);` where `TestClass` has the property mapping, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Alas, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69016/discussion-between-ahmed-okour-and-david-masters).

Comment: Could you try with `indexType="TOKENIZED"` and `type="System.Double"`? You might need to do `i => (double)i[(ObjectIndexerKey)"price"]` as suggested by Ahmed as well.

Also, if you turn on debug logging and look in the Search log we should get some more information about how Sitecore actually parses your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your property name has to be dynamic, You could try the following code for sorting on numeric field:

```
return queryable.OrderBy(i => (double)i[(ObjectIndexerKey)"price"]);
```

Set Your field config to use System.Double :

```
<field fieldName="price" 
   storageType="YES" 
   indexType="TOKENIZED" 
   vectorType="NO" 
   boost="1f" 
   type="System.Double" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```

You can ask Sitecore to use IndexFieldFloatingPointNumberValueConverter as default converter for any double value using this Patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
          <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>
            <converters>
              <converter handlesType="System.Double" typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Converters.IndexFieldFloatingPointNumberValueConverter , Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
            </converters>
          </indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>
        </defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**: I changed the field to be TOKENIZED as this is how it should be

Comment: This actually did work (without the converter config). I'm not sure why I couldn't get it to work when I first tried using this, I must have had the config wrong or forgot to rebuild the index.